# How to convert the ConfigProperties_server1.props which is extracted from websphere using wsadmin to xml or json file?

Tags: java, json, xml, websphere, jython

This is the Jython script I have used to extract the ConfigProperties_server1.props file:

```
AdminTask.extractConfigProperties('[-propertiesFileName ConfigProperties_server1.props -configData Server=server1]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.  The `AdminTask.extractConfigProperties` command has no option to control the format of the file.  The option `PortablePropertiesFile` might sound promising, but instead it controls whether internal XMI ids are included in the props file.  You're going to have to parse the properties file and convert it yourself, the syntax of the file is documented in [this IBM KnowledgeCenter topic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rxml_prop_file_syntax.html).  Given the complexity of this task, you may want to edit your question and add some detail on what you're trying to accomplish by converting to xml or json format file, so perhaps the community might better help you.

Comment: i am creating a diagnostic tool that reads the configuration setting.compare each against the predefined list and report in case of any mismatch ,so for that now i have extracted the configuration i need to convert it into json to compare the 2 json files which will be easy to do

Comment: IBM provides a tool to compare configs, see https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg22010928